# Azure REST API access with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, api, oauth

I'm currently developing some powershell scripts that interface with the Azure API. I am finding that some api access is with only available via REST (takes a little time to be present on the AZCLI or Powershell) and access via REST also is a lot faster.

Does anybody have any good resources that takes you through the process of using REST within Powershell? These must include the steps for creating the application in Azure and how to authenticate and access an Oauth token ( im aware of the invoke-restmethod but unsure how I get a authentication token).

Any help appreciated. thx.

Comment: https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/

Comment: Creating the application in Azure is easily implemented with `New-AzureADApplication` cmd. I don't think it's only available via REST. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0.

Comment: Thanks @AmitBaranes that article helped be get past the initial problem. Once I got it working in Postman I then changed it to work in Powershell. Thanks.

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: THanks. Also found this resource after I configured it all which was quite useful and pretty succinct https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/9/23/powershell-and-azure-rest-api-authentication

Answer (score 0):

See both links:-

https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/9/23/powershell-and-azure-rest-api-authentication
https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/

Thanks for helping.